# When a nonlinear equation is regular?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, nonlinear-analysis

I was solving a nonlinear equation in matlab using the function fsolve. Matlab says "*the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient*". In the definition of *problem appears regular* it is written that:

The problem appears to be regular means the size of the gradient of the sum of squares of function values is less than the OptimalityTolerance tolerance (1e-4*OptimalityTolerance for the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm).

My questions are:

> What does it mean for a problem to be regular? Is there a formal definition?

and

> Is there an analytic way to prove that a nonlinear equation is regular?